# Change Cloud URL using SimpleLink App for TI CC3200 SensorTags

Tags: mqtt, raspberry-pi, ti-cc3200

I have some TI CC3200 Sensortags WiFi which I want to use *out-of-the-box* (without programming anything)

### Purpose

I want to send the sensor information from the sensortags to an MQTT broker running on a Raspberry Pi 3 via WiFi.

According to the [User Guide for CC3200 WiFi Sensortags](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC3200_SensorTag_Users_Guide) I have downloaded the app for Android and configured the app as mentioned in the user guide.

Within the App I configured the Sensortag to send information to a WLAN access point which in turn is connected to the Internet. The moment the tag is configured it sends out information via MQTT to an IBM Cloud Endpoint automatically.

I tried clicking on the `Cloud URL` tab on the Android app but it doesn't do anything.

Instead of sending the sensor information to the cloud I wish to send this information to the MQTT broker on the Raspberry Pi 3 via the App. How is this possible?